# Plot matrix with colored circles according to value

Tags: r, matrix, plot

As part of an assignment, I am supposed to plot a numerical matrix by assigning colored circles to the matrix entries (same color for the same entries). Here is an example:

[image: Desired visuals]

My code generates a matrix similar to the one in the sample code below.

```
#Matrix prep
matrix_test <- matrix(sample(c(0,1,2), replace=TRUE, size=100), nrow=10, ncol=10)


#Plotting
par(mar=c(0,0,1,0), bty="n", pch="O", lty=2)
plot(c(-1,ncol(matrix_test)),c(0,nrow(matrix_test)+1), type="n", xlab="",ylab="", asp=1)
```

I then try to generate the required output with the following code:

```
#Coloring
colors <- matrix(sapply(matrix_test, function(x) ifelse(x <= 0, "white", ifelse(x == 2, "red",ifelse(x == 3, "green",ifelse(x == 4, "blue","cyan"))))),ncol=ncol(matrix_test))
for (r in 1:nrow(matrix_test))
  for (c in 1:ncol(matrix_test)) {
    rect(c-1, r-1, c, r, col=colors[nrow(matrix_test) - r + 1,c])
  }
```

[image: My code generates this output]

As you can see, instead of the circles, the whole box is colored according to the number. I've found many potential ways of accomplishing this with additional packages, but am not allowed to use these for this assignment.

I am fairly new to R, so please excuse me if I am overseeing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `points` with `pch=19` to get filled circles, and `cex` to control the diameter:

```
#Matrix prep
matrix_test <- 
  matrix(sample(c(0,1,2), replace=TRUE, size=100), nrow=10, ncol=10)
zeros <- which(matrix_test == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
ones <- which(matrix_test == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
twos <- which(matrix_test == 2, arr.ind = TRUE)

#Plotting
par(mar=c(0,0,1,0), bty="n", pch="O", lty=2)
plot(c(-1,ncol(matrix_test)), c(0,nrow(matrix_test)+1), type="n", 
     xlab=NA, ylab=NA, asp=1)
points(zeros, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "red")
points(ones, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "green")
points(twos, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "blue")
```

[image]